# Firebird SQL проверка монопольного режима

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

У СУБД Firebird есть монопольный режим (shutdown), при котором к БД может подключаться только админ, и не более одного соединения. Используется для выполнения всяких критичных вещей и сервисного обслуживания.

Извне при помощи Service API я могу проверить, находится ли база в монопольном режиме.

Но возникла необходимость выполнять проверку внутр хранимой процедуры - если БД не в монопольном режиме выдать исключение.

Возможно ли это, и если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=gdscode

Может быть так? Вот этот код при shutdown может вовращаться - 335544528.

Comment: Нет. Эту ошибку получат все кроме меня, выполняющего работу монопольно.

Comment: Извините. Из Вашего сообщения неправильно понял. Теперь ясно, что Вы хотите из-под админа это проверить, работая с базой в shutdown.